# Position background and center at same time

Tags: css

I'm spriting an image:

```
#himgstsi {
    background: url(headimg.jpg) no-repeat top center 0px -250px;
}
```

This obviously does not work.

Is there any way I can center the background to the center of the page but ALSO sprite the image?

I'm aware they both positioning tags, but is there an easy way to do this without wrapping a div inside a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
#himgstsi {
    background: url(headimg.jpg) no-repeat 50% -250px;
}
```